# React and Firebase image upload showing net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, next.js

Several hours I am facing the which is `net::ERR_TIMED_OUT` when I try to upload an image into Firebase.

Here is my configuration:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
const config = {
    apiKey: "example",
    authDomain: "example",
    databaseURL: "example",
    projectId: "example",
    storageBucket: "example",
    messagingSenderId: "example",
    appId: "example"
};
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();
export {
    auth,
    firebase,
    storage
};
```

Storage Roles:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write: if auth != null; // tried also if true
        }
    }
}
```

In my form component:

```
import { storage } from '../../firebase';
state = {
    image: null,
    url: ''
};

handleChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.files[0]){
        const image = e.target.files[0];
        this.setState(() => ({ image }))
    }
    // console.log(e.target.files[0])
}

handleUpload = () => {
    const { image } = this.state;
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
    (snapshot) => {
        // progress function ....
    }, 
    (error) => {
        // Error function
        console.log(error)
    }, 
    () => {
        // Complete function
        storage.ref('images').child(image.name).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            console.log(url)
        })
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input 
                type="file" 
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

That was my setup but after click to upload it's showing `net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`.

On the other hand, the insert, update, delete working fine with Firebase but the issue in images.

What should now, please?

Thanks